# multiset.end() return value in C++

Tags: c++, vector, multiset

Why does multiset.end() return a different value when compared to vector.end().

```
int main(){
    multiset<int>v={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    cout<<*v.end()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In case of multiset, it returns a value of total elements present in the multiset.

```
int main(){
    vector<int>v={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    cout<<*v.end()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Whereas vector returns 0.

Comment: Both of these invoke *undefined behavior* when dereferencing an end-iterator.

Comment: Both of your examples produces a big `assert` dialog box when run using Visual C++ under the debug runtime, all because of the dereferencing of `end()`.  Thus nothing got printed.